# Laravel, delete related data from Database

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I have 3 tables that should be related, but they aren't:

```
'tables' <-- this is a normal Laravel table with created_at and updated_at
--------
id|name
--------
5 |people


'filters' <-- this is a normal Laravel table with created_at and updated_at
-------------
id | table_id
-------------
10 | 5


'filter_users' <- this is a pivot table
-------------
user_id|filter_id
-------------
 66    | 10
```

I need that when someone deletes a row from 'table', also deletes from 'filter' and 'filter_users'

This 3 values:

```
table.id = 5 -> filters.id = 10 -> filter_users.filter_id = 10
```

It's enough on setting `FK` on both 'filters' and 'filter_users' table with `DELETE CASCADE` with:

```
ALTER TABLE public.filters ADD CONSTRAINT filters_fk FOREIGN KEY (table_id) REFERENCES public."tables"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

or should I use some restrictions on the Models?

Comment: If this is a `belongsToMany()/many-to-many` relationship, you wouldn't want to delete anything in `filters` if you delete something in `tables`, as it could relate to another record in `tables`. Deleting the intermediate data is as simple as doing `$table->filters()->detach();` (assuming you have the correct relationships defined)

Comment: I tried what I put about CASCADE but I've been getting a lot of errors due old data with id that doesn't exists anymore in one table or another. What you said sounds correct, but the code here is a mess about custom ways for deleting, insert, etc, with raw sql inside. I'll have to put more raw sql inside `Table` model for delete "in cascade" what I need :(

Comment: you can simply add cascade for filter and filter_users table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger without having a constraint

```
  Create trigger sample
  After DELETE on
  Table for Each Row

  DELETE FROM FILTERS F JOIN
  FILTER_USERS FU ON 
  New.ID=F.TABLEID AND
  F.ID=FU.FILTERID
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

The databse solution with `ON DELETE CASCADE` is good enough in most cases, until you use `SoftDelete` on your models.

In that case, `ON DELETE CASCADE` won't be triggered since it's just an update. You might still make it work with `trigger` as @Himanshu said, but you will need to set both triggers (update and delete).

One last solution, and not the best one, is to do it via code, by overloading your `delete()` method in your model.